# How to make tabbing between fields work in a Frame in wxPython

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython

I am very new to wxPython and I have used the following tutorial to create a couple of TextCtrl fields and stuff.
http://sebsauvage.net/python/gui/#import

Everything works except that I cant switch between the fields using the Tab button which is very annoying. How could I modify the example in that tutorial (with some more TextCtrl added to it) such that I can use tab to switch between the fields?

If you dont want to look at the tutorial, its basicalyl a frame with a bunch of TextCtrl put on it using a GridBagSizer.

When searching on the net all I found was "create a panel", but I tried that and since I am very new to wxPython it didnt work and I could not find a thorough tutorial on how to do that (and if possible Id like to stick with only a frame...)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a wx.Panel to the frame and then give the panel object as the parent to all the other widgets. The wx.Panel adds the tabbing capability and makes the frame look right on all platforms (right color, mostly). If you don't have the panel, then tabbing won't work.

See this thread where Robin Dunn, creator of wxPython, says the same thing: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/wxpython-users/gF8r_HwnOEU

Answer (score 0):

Here is something that I made before, it isn't very good but I can assume that you can add to it as you want

```
import os
import wx

class tab(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent, newid=0, name="New Tab", file=None, aNewTab=False):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.control = wx.TextCtrl(self, style=wx.TE_MULTILINE)
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer()
        sizer.Add(self.control, -1, wx.EXPAND, newid)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)
        if file != None:
            self.control.write(file)
        else:
            pass

class MainWindow(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, title=title, size=(1000,900))
        self.CreateStatusBar()

        self.buttons = []

        filemenu = wx.Menu()
        helpmenu = wx.Menu()

        menuOpen = filemenu.Append(wx.ID_OPEN, "&Open", "Open a file to edit")
        menuSave = filemenu.Append(wx.ID_SAVE, "&Save", "Save the current file")
        menuSaveAs = filemenu.Append(wx.ID_SAVEAS, "&Save As", "Save the current file as")
        menuExit = filemenu.Append(wx.ID_EXIT, "E&xit", "Terminate the program")
        menuAbout = helpmenu.Append(wx.ID_ABOUT, "&About", "Information about this program,")

        menuBar = wx.MenuBar()
        menuBar.Append(filemenu, "&File") 
        menuBar.Append(helpmenu, "&Help")
        self.SetMenuBar(menuBar)

        self.openFiles = { }


        self.p = wx.Panel(self)
        self.nb = wx.Notebook(self.p)
        self.newTab = tab(self.nb)
        self.nb.AddPage(self.newTab, "New Tab")
        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer()
        self.sizer.Add(self.nb, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.p.SetSizer(self.sizer)

        #new ids
        saveid = wx.NewId()
        openid = wx.NewId()
        boldid = wx.NewId()

        #Set Events
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnAbout, menuAbout)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnExit, menuExit)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnOpen, menuOpen)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnSave, menuSave)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnSave, menuSaveAs)
        # Events that are activated when buttons are pressed
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnSave, id=saveid)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnOpen, id=openid)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnBold, id=boldid)

        self.accel_tbl = wx.AcceleratorTable([(wx.ACCEL_CTRL, ord('S'), saveid),
                                              (wx.ACCEL_CTRL, ord('O'), openid),
                                              (wx.ACCEL_CTRL, ord('B'), boldid)])
        self.SetAcceleratorTable(self.accel_tbl)

        self.Show(True)

    def OnAbout(self,e):
        dlg = wx.MessageDialog(self, "A simple text editor", "About Simple Editor", wx.OK)
        dlg.ShowModal()
        dlg.Destroy()

    def OnExit(self,e):
        if self.control.IsModified:
            dlg = wx.MessageDialog(self, "If you quit now all your work will be erased. Do you still want to quit?", "Are You Sure?", wx.YES_NO | wx.ICON_QUESTION)
            a = dlg.ShowModal()
            if a == wx.ID_YES:
                self.Close(True)
            else:
                self.OnSave(self, True)

    def OnOpen(self,e):
        """
        Open a File
        """
        self.dirname = ''
        dlg = wx.FileDialog(self, "Choose a file", self.dirname, "", "*.*", wx.FD_OPEN)
        if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
            self.filename = dlg.GetFilename()
            self.dirname = dlg.GetDirectory()
            f = open(os.path.join(self.dirname, self.filename), 'r')
        newTab = tab(self.nb, name=self.filename, file=f.read(), aNewTab=True)
        self.nb.AddPage(newTab, "%s" %(self.filename))
        f.close()
        self.SetTitle("Simple Editor - %s" %(self.filename))
        dlg.Destroy()

    def OnSave(self,e, exit=False):
        """
        Save a file
        """
        #if self.newTab.control.IsEmpty():
            #dlg = wx.
        self.dirname = ''
        dlg = wx.FileDialog(self, "Where do you want to save this file?", self.dirname, "", "*.*", wx.FD_SAVE)
        if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
            self.filename = dlg.GetFilename()
            self.dirname = dlg.GetDirectory()
            f = open(os.path.join(self.dirname, self.filename), 'w')
            a = str(self.control.GetValue())
            f.write(a)
            f.close()
        dlg.Destroy()
        if exit != False:
            self.Close(True)
        self.SetTitle("Simple Editor - %s" %(self.filename))

app = wx.App(False)
frame = MainWindow(None, "Simple Editor")
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Im not sure thats what im looking for (and I cant run that code anyway). Could you please point to the code that makes it possible to switch between the fields with the tab button?

Comment: It looks like you misunderstood the OP's question. They're asking about the tab *button*, not adding tabs to their UI.

Comment: oops, sorry about that, you could just add an event that responds to a key press, check the key, if its tab then run a function like OnTab()

Comment: I got it working using a panel now. Dont know why it doesnt work with  a Frame though but I guess it is not important. So case closed.

Comment: frames in wxPython are the windows of the GUI, a panel is like a frame in a frame